# Quantum physics book linking experimental data with theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations

Kindly recommend book or resource which links quantum physics experimental data with theory. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Some suggestion are here are R. C. Fernow, Introduction to Experimental Particle Physics The Picture Book of Quantum Mechanics

But start is from max planck and here below are links to very important first papers which gave birth to quantum  physics

First
...................................................................

https://www.scielo.br › rbefPDF
Max Planck's Determination of the Avogadro Constant

Second
....................................................................

https://www.gsjournal.net/Science-Journals-Papers/Author/544/Max,%20Planck

Third
....................................................................

Einstein's paper on quanta of photon

The Information Philosopher
https://www.informationphilosopher.com › ...PDF
Einstein's Proposal of the Photon Concept—a Translation of the ...

Fourth
....................................................................

Einstein's paper on Relativivity

http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Einstein_1905_relativity.pdf

Fifth
....................................................................

Einstein's Mass Energy equivalence

https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/232514/Einstein%20E=mc2%20(pp172-174).pdf

Sixth
..................................................................

De Broglie theory of quanta

https://fondationlouisdebroglie.org/LDB-oeuvres/De_Broglie_Kracklauer.pdf

Seventh
..........................................................

Schrodinger paper on his equation

https://people.isy.liu.se/jalar/kurser/QF/references/Schrodinger1926c.pdf

---

Then walton cockroft atom splitting was successful experiment which did not prove anything  scientifically but used all above theories to succeed in running the experiment and a good book like particle phisics experiments at high energy Colliders will give clearer perspective

Then quantum chemistry and solid state physics good books (like kittle) leading to excellent book ideas of quantum chemistry should help develop further

And latestly (not lastely) freeman dyson maps being used for implementation of quantum computing  -- haven't seen book about such miracle yet

Answer (score 2):

*The New Quantum Universe* by Tony Hey and Patrick Walters does a very good job of connecting experimental results with the theories that explain those results.

Answer (score 0):

Larkoski’s intuitive intro to particle physics consistently compares experiments to theory, and even has you analyze data yourself!

Answer (score 0):

The two-volume work by Ruark and Urey, *Atoms, Molecules, and Quanta* (1930, 1964) is an excellent reference work on quantum physics originally published in the early days of quantum mechanics. The first volume covers spectroscopy, the old quantum theory, x-rays; the second volume starts with critical potentials and scattering, then develops wave and matrix mechanics along historical lines before entering into the general theory of quantum mechanics and spectra of molecules. It's a favorite of mine for its connection with the history of quantum mechanics and its experimental foundations. It will not, of course, have more recent results (or anything beyond roughly 1930).